# Why doesn't Flurry logerror:message:exception method get called?

Tags: objective-c, flurry

I have just set up Flurry to track uncaught exceptions but it is not being called.

1. I have the most recent Flurry SDK.
2. In the AppDelegate.m I have imported "Flurry.h"
3. I have the following method to log errors:

   ```
   void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception){ 
     [Flurry logError:@"Uncaught" message:@"Crash!" exception:exception];
   }
   ```

4 .In application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I have set the following:

```
 - [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
 - NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
 - [Flurry startSession:@"flurry key"];
```

I have purposely written some code to make the app crash but I don't see anything getting logged in Flurry. (Flurry.com/Events/Event Logs) I have been crashing the app since yesterday.
I am using an ipad not the simulator to test.

Answer (score 2):

Calling order should be this way,

```
[Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
[Flurry startSession:@"flurry key"];

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may have to be in the app store for Flurry to report crashes..

Try `bugsnag` for error handling, it is much better. Flurry is awesome at analytics, but bugs are better reported at `bugsnag`.